# Redirect 301 Not Working Fine

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to do a simple Redirect 301 but I'm experiencing an issue in this case:

This is my redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /negocios/wisconsin/wi/ www.domain.com/directorio/category/121/Wisconsin.html
```

When I enter this URL:

```
www.domain.com/negocios/wisconsin/wi/servicios-multiples/
```

It applies the Redirect rule and sends the browser to this URL:

```
www.domain.com/directorio/category/121/Wisconsin.htmlservicios-multiples/
```

Which is a WRONG url. Probably because a part of the URL (/negocios/wisconsin/wi/) is similar to the URL I'm trying to redirect.

How I can do to apply the Redirect ONLY to this URL (/negocios/wisconsin/wi/) even if I enter another URL similar like for example

```
www.domain.com/negocios/wisconsin/wi/WHATEVER-HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/negocios/wisconsin/wi/$ www.domain.com/directorio/category/121/Wisconsin.html
```

This tells apache only to redirect on the exact match instead of linking path nodes together, which is what `Redirect` does.